# Swift: Adding Audio to AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, swift, avmutablecomposition, avcomposition

I'm using the code in the answer to the question posted here (added below):
[Swift 3: How to add watermark on video ? AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool iOS 10 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530367/swift-3-how-to-add-watermark-on-video-avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool-ios/45250616)

The code strips the video track from a recorded video and adds a watermark. The code doesn't merge the audio track so the output is the watermarked video with no audio.

How can I merge the audio back into the watermarked video?

The code:
    import UIKit
    import AssetsLibrary
    import AVFoundation
    import Photos

```
enum QUWatermarkPosition {
case TopLeft
case TopRight
case BottomLeft
case BottomRight
case Default
}

class QUWatermarkManager: NSObject {

func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
    self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: nil, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
        completion!(status, session, outputURL)
    }
}

func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, imageName name : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
    self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: nil, imageName: name, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
        completion!(status, session, outputURL)
    }
}

private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
        do {
            try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize

        let parentLayer = CALayer()
        let videoLayer = CALayer()
        parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

        if text != nil {
            let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
            titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            titleLayer.string = text
            titleLayer.font = "Helvetica" as CFTypeRef
            titleLayer.fontSize = 15
            titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
            titleLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            parentLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
        } else if name != nil {
            let watermarkImage = UIImage(named: name)
            let imageLayer = CALayer()
            imageLayer.contents = watermarkImage?.cgImage

            var xPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
            var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
            let imageSize : CGFloat = 57.0

            switch (position) {
            case .TopLeft:
                xPosition = 0
                yPosition = 0
                break
            case .TopRight:
                xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                yPosition = 0
                break
            case .BottomLeft:
                xPosition = 0
                yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                break
            case .BottomRight, .Default:
                xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                break
            }


            imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
            imageLayer.opacity = 0.65
            parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
        }

        let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
        videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
        videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
        _ = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack

        let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)

        instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
        videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] 
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(date).mov")

        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        exporter?.outputURL = url
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp

        exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                    let outputURL = exporter?.outputURL
                    if flag {
                        // Save to library
//                            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

                        if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL!.path) {
                            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
                            }) { saved, error in
                                if saved {
                                    completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                                }
                            }
                        }

//                            if library.videoAtPathIs(compatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL) {
//                                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
//                                                                           completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
//                                                                            
//                                                                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, exporter, outputURL)
//                                })
//                            }
                    } else {
                        completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                    }

                } else {
                    // Error
                    completion!(exporter?.status, exporter, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
    var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
    var isPortrait = false
    if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
    } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
    } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
    }
    return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
}

private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

    let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

    var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
    if assetInfo.isPortrait {
        scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor),
                                 at: kCMTimeZero)
    } else {
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
        if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
            let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
            let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
            let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
            concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
        }
        instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)
    }

    return instruction
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following code achieved my goal:

```
let compositionAudioVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

let audioMix: AVMutableAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
var audioMixParam: [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters] = []

let assetVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]
let videoParam: AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: assetVideoTrack)
videoParam.trackID = compositionAudioVideo.trackID

audioMixParam.append(videoParam)

do {
    try compositionAudioVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: assetVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch _ {
            assertionFailure()
      }

audioMix.inputParameters = audioMixParam
```